# when i am giving border having issue in header?

Tags: html, css, css-float

When i am giving border in the bottom its going up and header is going down as we can see in the code pink line border going up i want that below the full name

i am using the reference of this site and making it by my own https://codepen.io/techie4good/pen/RGNBPQ?q=resume&limit=techie4good

```css
body {
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 1.1em;
  width: 75%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.main {
  color: #4EC5C1;
}

#name {
  float: left;
}

#contact {
  float: right;
  list-style-type: none;
}

#workExperiance {
  float: left;
}

header {
  border-bottom: solid 2px pink;
  margin: 70px;
}
```

```html
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <title>Full Name Resume</title>
  <meta charset=utf-8>
</head>

<body>
  <header>
    <section>
      <h1 id="name"><span class="main">full </span> Name</h1>
    </section>
    <section>
      <ul id="contact">
        <li><span class="main">Cell:</span> +1-000000000</li>
        <li><span class="main">Email: </span> aaaaaa@gmail.com</li>
        <li><span class="main">Location:</span> NY,USA.</li>
      </ul>
    </section>
  </header>
  <section id="workExperiance">Work Experience</section>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add `float: left;width: 100%;` to `.header` class

```css
body {
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 1.1em;
  width: 75%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.main {
  color: #4EC5C1;
}

#name {
  float: left;
}

#contact {
  float: right;
  list-style-type: none;
}

#workExperiance {
  float: left;
}

header {
  border-bottom: solid 2px pink;
  margin: 70px;
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <title>Full Name Resume</title>
  <meta charset=utf-8>
</head>

<body>
  <header>
    <section>
      <h1 id="name"><span class="main">full </span> Name</h1>
    </section>
    <section>
      <ul id="contact">
        <li><span class="main">Cell:</span> +1-000000000</li>
        <li><span class="main">Email: </span> aaaaaa@gmail.com</li>
        <li><span class="main">Location:</span> NY,USA.</li>
      </ul>
    </section>
  </header>
  <section id="workExperiance">Work Experience</section>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add these line of `CSS` code:

```
header:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}
```

```css
body {
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 1.1em;
  width: 75%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.main {
  color: #4EC5C1;
}

#name {
  float: left;
}

#contact {
  float: right;
  list-style-type: none;
}

#workExperiance {
  float: left;
}

header {
  border-bottom: solid 2px pink;
  margin: 70px;
}

header:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}
```

```html
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <title>Full Name Resume</title>
  <meta charset=utf-8>
</head>

<body>
  <header>
    <section>
      <h1 id="name"><span class="main">full </span> Name</h1>
    </section>
    <section>
      <ul id="contact">
        <li><span class="main">Cell:</span> +1-000000000</li>
        <li><span class="main">Email: </span> aaaaaa@gmail.com</li>
        <li><span class="main">Location:</span> NY,USA.</li>
      </ul>
    </section>
  </header>
  <section id="workExperiance">Work Experience</section>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: No need to add `space` between double quotation. It works without that.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently that float:left was the offender... Removed it and it works...

```css
body {
      font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
      font-size: 1.1em; 
      width: 75%;
      margin: 0 auto;
    }
    .main{color: #4EC5C1;}
    #contact{float:right;list-style-type:none;}
    #workExperiance{float:left;}
    header{border-bottom:solid 2px pink; margin: 70px;}
```

```html
<html lang="en">
    
    <head>
      <title>Full Name Resume</title>
      <meta charset=utf-8>
    </head>
    
    <body>
      <header>
        <section>
          <h1><span class="main">full </span> Name</h1>
        </section>
        <section>
          <ul id="contact">
            <li><span class="main">Cell:</span> +1-000000000</li>
            <li><span class="main">Email: </span> aaaaaa@gmail.com</li>
            <li><span class="main">Location:</span> NY,USA.</li>
          </ul>
        </section>
      </header>
      <section id="workExperiance">Work Experience</section>
    </body>
    
    </html>
```

Comment: what does that mean why its happening sir you have solved the current issue but what was the reason for such issue can you give little detail so if someone having same such issue they can refer this answer. what i am doing wrong and what should be done and by adding your element what happens can elaborate

Comment: Based on w3schools, "Elements after a floating element will flow around it." Therefore when you use float:left or right, the other elements tries to float around it (i.e) Every other element starts to the right or left of the "float" element... Thus for this example, the border you created floats "around" (i.e) above the tag... Thus either float:none or float:inherit or even float:initial will help in "supressing" the other elements floating around it...